# wording of modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Should we say find the inverse of a residue modulo n or find the inverse of an integer modulo n? I am trying to get the precise wording for an elementary number theory course.

Answer (score 0):

$ab \equiv 1 \pmod n$ is read $ab$ is congruent to $1 \pmod n$

and $b$ is the *modular multiplicative inverse* of $a \pmod{n}$ such that:

$a^{-1} \equiv b \pmod{n}$

Comment: Is it wrong to say b is the inverse of the residue a mod n?

Comment: It wouldn't sound that bad at all, but I've never seen nobody using that sentence before. The inverse operation is called modular multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. My only reservation is modular multiplicative inverse is bit of a mouthfull and not clear what it actually means but if this is the correct term then I'll use it. Much appreciated.